# Meta transaction using ethers.js

Tags: meta-transactions, ethers.js

How can I implement a meta transaction using `ethers.js` library.

My transaction is to transfer **100 tokens** from `0xAccountA` to `0xAccountB`.

The transaction will be signed by `0xAccountA` but the gas should be payed by some other `0xAccountC`.

Comment: Coming across this specific issue , did you find any solution about this?

Comment: Really, did you ?